# Does legacy of the void include all heroes introduced in starcraft until then?

Tags: starcraft-2

Does starcraft 2: legacy of the void being the latest expansion include all the new units introduced in both heart of the swarm and wings of liberty?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll find all of the new units in the previous expansions. There are specific missions in the single player campaign that have you playing Zerg and Terran and you can build all of the new units. On the missions that you play the Protoss, you'll find yourself up against all of the newer units as well.